# My rake tasks can't seem to have other objects in scope?

Tags: ruby, scope, rake

(I'm not using Rails)

I have a rake task that sets the environment that was passed in like:

```
rake some:task ENV=test
```

My task is:

```
  desc "environment"
  task :environment do
    env = ENV['ENV'] || 'development'
  end
```

Now if I have a task like:

```
 desc "t1"
  task :t1 [:environment] do
    puts env
  end
```

It fails saying env isn't known, why is that?

I thought the dynamic nature of ruby would do this:

When running the environment task, it would create env variable, and since it is a dependancy that variable would be in scope of my other tasks.

How can I have it so it is in scope?

Note: in case it matters, some of my tasks are in different .rake files, just mentioning if that changes anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Rakefile is just like any other Ruby code. Block variables (variables created inside `do-end`) are local to the block.

To make your `env` variable visible in other blocks just assign it to an instance variable instead:

```
@env = ENV['ENV'] ...
...
puts @env
```

Or you could use a constant too:

```
MYENV = ENV['ENV'] ....
...
puts MYENV
```

Or create the variable outside the block scope before you use it:

```
env = nil

task :environment do
  env = ENV['ENV'] ....
end

task :othertask ... do
  puts env
end
```